# how can i convert rows to columns: License Number, Name, Address, City/ST/Zip, Phone, License Expiration Date with their values in rows

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

How can I make 6 columns and get corresponding values in rows?

License number in license no column, all names under Name column, All addresses under Address column, etc.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| License Number: | M-3200 |
| Name: | ABREGO,JEREMY D. |
| Address: | 1550 WISCONSIN AVENUE |
| City/ST/Zip: | BENSON MN 56215 |
| Phone: | 3207606827 |
| License Expiration Date: | 31/12/2023 |
| License Number: | M-3051 |
| Name: | ADAMSON, ANDY J. |
| Address: | 38130 BEACH ST. |
| City/ST/Zip: | WARROAD MN 56763 |
| Phone: | 7015203337 |
| License Expiration Date: | 31/12/2022 |
| License Number: | I-2558 |
| Name: | AINSWORTH,VALEN A. |
| Address: | 1691 PALACE AVENUE |
| City/ST/Zip: | ST. PAUL MN 55105 |
| Phone: | 5126407335 |
| License Expiration Date: | 31/12/2023 |
| License Number: | M-3695 |

Comment: Check out the function `TRANSPOSE()`. MS Support shows an example under this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027) that illustrates what you are after.

Comment: Google sheets or Excel? Please edit the tags to reflect which app you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Try `VSTACK()` with `WRAPROWS()`.

```
=VSTACK(TOROW(UNIQUE(A1:A18)),WRAPROWS(B1:B18,6))
```

[image]